# DSLR Backpack for Travelling?

Tags: travel, camera-bag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gear for carrying and storing a DSLR on a backpacking trip?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/gear-for-carrying-and-storing-a-dslr-on-a-backpacking-trip)

I will be going on a missions trip this summer for two months. I want to be able to carry my Canon Rebel T3 with me out in the field but I also want to be able to carry other items with me. I'm not really going to have any other camera accessories besides the camera itself with the attached lens. So, I'm looking for a backpack with a small area of safety for my camera but also room for items I will need while on the field all day. Being that I will need to raise as much money as I can for the trip, the cheapest option would be ideal. Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question will fit your camera easily and is one of the cheapest camera bag styles.