# How good is the Lowepro Fastpack 250?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag, accessories

I am planning to buy a backpack for my Nikon D90 and after some analysis and research I am thinking about getting a [Lowepro Fastpack 250](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YIYQ30).

My requirements are not very high, since I am not a professional who tends to carry a lot of lenses and other accessories.

Right now I am confused because I have found the following variations of the model that I mentioned

1. Lowepro Fastpack 250 Camera/Laptop Backpack.
2. Lowepro Backpack Fastpack 250

Could you help me to discriminate between the two, in terms of features, usability, fit for my needs?

Here is the link where I saw them: [Lowepro+Fastpack+250](http://www.junglee.com/mn/search/junglee/ref=nav_sb_noss?k=Lowepro%20Fastpack%20250&i=aps).

In addition, I would like to know if there is a way to place a tripod on the Lowepro Fastpack 250.  I have not found any details about this on the product detail page.

I mostly do photography while travelling, which includes both bike trips (maximum) and trips by my car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purchased the 350 (as it allows for a 17" laptop) and I am very happy with it.

It is comfortable to wear. It feels solidly build, and there is definitely room for enough lenses. During one trip I was fortunate to borrow some equipment, and I could store the following equipment in the lower camera compartment:

- Entry level dSLR
- 70-200mm f/4 lens
- 50mm f/1.4 lens
- 10-22mm lens
- 24-105mm lens
- Speedlite flash.

So quite roomy. The upper compartment was used for cleaning cloths, filters, remote, etc.

The only thing lacking is a way to place a tripod on it. But I managed to get mine stored horizontally placed underneath the flap that covers the camera compartment. I had one leg on the outside, and two legs on the inside, to hold it it place, and it did work.

Dedicated straps for a tripod would have been a very welcome addition to this otherwise excellent backpack.

Comment: yes, only difference is for the 17" and 15" and i do not see my self going for 17" in near future.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Lowepro 250 backpack.  I wasn't aware there was a non-laptop version.  Looking at your link all four listings appear to have a laptop compartment; the difference appears to be one of name only.

It is an excellent bag. Its main shortcoming is the lack of ability to carry tripods, monopods and/or lightstands.

I have, however, carried two slr bodies, three lenses, two strobes, radio triggers, mini tripods, a tablet, gaffer tape, batteries and other accoutrements using the top and bottom compartments.  I generally carry one (or two at a push) collapsible reflectors in the laptop compartment.

Even when fully packed, the back stays inside (UK) cabin baggage allowances. It is comfortable to wear all day, walking many miles, even in warm weather.  I have recommended this to several people in my local photo club, and am happy to continue to do so.

Comment: i believe beside the tripod issue, this is a good option overall?

Comment: It certainly is for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [Lowepro webpage for the Fastpack series](http://www.lowepro.com/fastpack) you'll see that there are two versions, and that the main difference is that one (AW version) comes with all weather cover. The backpack contains an compartment for a laptop, is this something you need?

I don't have the fastpack myself, but I have an older CompuDaypack which is fine for normal walking, but not good for biking. I've been looking at the [Photo Sport 200 AW](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Photo-Sport-200-AW,2271,14.htm) or something similar for when I need a backpack for more active trips (hiking / biking). You can also have a look at the question [Gear for carrying and storing a DSLR on a backpacking trip?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/gear-for-carrying-and-storing-a-dslr-on-a-backpacking-trip)

Comment: well laptop is not in my list, its like all this series was providing this option :)

Comment: Then you might want to find a backpack without a laptop compartment. It adds extra weight and "steals" a lot of volume that could be used better.

Comment: do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Have a look at the answers to the question [Gear for carrying and storing a DSLR on a backpacking trip?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/gear-for-carrying-and-storing-a-dslr-on-a-backpacking-trip) for tips about backpacks for "active" trips.

Answer (score 0):

I have one and I've been quite pleased with it.

It is on the cheaper end of the range but being Lowepro is very well made.  It is not particularly large, which may not may not suit you.  I can just about fit a 5DMK2 (without grip), 24-70 2.8L and 70-200 2.8L IS II inside it with lens hoods but it's a tight squeeze.  It does have a laptop area too which is very convenient.

I think I have probably outgrown mine and may look for a slightly larger version in the not too distant future, but if you don't intend to use it to carry a lot of gear then it could be ideal.

The only other downside is that it's not really waterproof (it will be okay in a light shower) and doesn't come with a built in all-weather cover as some of the more expensive Lowepro bags do.

I have also used it to travel on short haul flights in the UK and Europe and it's always been absolutely fine as hand luggage.